# Are static variables inlined by default inside templates in C++17?

Tags: c++, templates, inline, c++17

Are static variables inlined by default inside templates in C++17? Here's an example:

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeClass {
    static T test;
};

struct SomeClass2 {
    static constexpr int test = 9;
};
```

Are those variables inlined or still need an out of line definition to be ODR used?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A `static constexpr` will implicitly also be `inline`, otherwise you will need to mark it as `inline`

```
template<typename T>
struct SomeClass {
    inline static T test; // Now inline
};

struct SomeClass2 {
    static constexpr int test = 9; // inline
};
```

Cfr. from n4606 `[depr.static_constexpr]`

> For compatibility with prior C++ International Standards, a constexpr static data member may be redundantly redeclared outside the class with no initializer. This usage is deprecated.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   static constexpr int n = 5; // definition (declaration in C++ 2014)
> };
> const int A::n; // redundant declaration (definition in C++ 2014)
> ```

and `[dcl.constexpr]` (Barry beat me to it)

> A function or static data member declared with the constexpr specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable (7.1.6).

Answer (score 12):

From [dcl.constexpr]:

> A function or static data member declared with the `constexpr`
>   specifier is implicitly an inline function or variable (7.1.6).

There is no such implicit `inline` for static (non-`constexpr`) data members of class templates. However, in C++17, we can now mark variables themselves as `inline`, [dcl.inline]:

> A variable declaration with an `inline` specifier declares an inline variable.